# Validation asserts being ignored in symfony2?

Tags: validation, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to get a form validated but its behavior is strange, I'm a newbie in symfony2 so I must be missing something.

I use [SonataAdminBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle) to create forms and CRUD controller. My `ResponsableDato` entity has this property:

```
/**
 * @var string $contacto
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.")
 * @Assert\Length(min="3", minMessage="too short."))
 * @ORM\Column(name="contacto", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $contacto;
```

If I leave `contacto` field blank it gives me `"Complete this field"` message instead of `"Please enter your name"`. If I type one character it passes `NotBlank` validation but ignores Length validation.

What could I be missing? It sounds as if I had to override something to get it to work

Comment: Shouldnt be min=3 instead of min="3"... and you close the paranthesis twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also you're talking about html5 validation or isValid() to form_errors() case?

i'm quite sure that "Complete this field" is related to "required" option in your form field

```
$builder->add('contacto', 'text', array('required' => false));
```

set required to false and see your custom error message :)

edit:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
[...]
/**
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $contacto;
```

this will fire validation error after submit, though if there's no data for this field in the form, if you need to avoid an empty string use @Assert\NotBlank()

Comment: I've just been told that symfony2 adds html5 validation, I don't know how. I added what you said and it didn't work: $formMapper ->add('contacto', null, array('label'=> 'contacto','required'=> false            )); but now it ignores my asserts in the entity even if i set nullable=false and NotBlank =(

Comment: first of all don't leave null as second parameter, use a whatsovever implementation of FormTypeInterface
second that "nullable" is related to the schema mapping, not form validation

    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
     private $contacto;

is what you're looking for

Comment: nope, with 'required' => false and event setting second parameter as 'text' still ignores all asserts, even:     /**
     * @var string $contacto * @ORM\Column(name="contacto", type="string", length=100, nullable=false) * @Assert\NotNull() */

Comment: if a set second parameter as null at least gets me maxlength="100" in the input tag, if a set it to 'text' it omits this attribute, it seems a looong learning curve for me and symfony2

Comment: please provide more data

1) your entity class
2) src/YourNamespace/YourBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml (if exists)
3) your custom FormType
4) the controller form validation section

Comment: my bad, i had another field with required=true, html5 wasn't letting me get to the Length assert! thanks man!

Comment: next time post the form using curl and check the response, this way you can bypass in-browser validation and be sure your form validation is working on the server side